# AWS Simple Email Service + Nodemailer = no errors in dev and in prod -- instant delivery in dev -- yet nothing is delivered in prod?

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, amazon-ses, vercel

I have been trouble shooting what the disconnect might be between production and development for sending emails using SES + Nodemailer in Nextjs. However, I can't seem to determine what is happening as there are no bounces in my SES console and no errors being logged to the dev console or real-time serverless function logs in production. The repo can be found [here](https://github.com/DopamineDriven/drisdell-consulting-services)

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

client-side form, `@components/Portals/nodemail.tsx`

```
import { Input, Button, Textarea, Logo, ModalBackdrop } from '@components/UI';
import { useState, SyntheticEvent, FC, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { useUI } from '@components/context';
import css from './contact-us.module.css';
import cn from 'classnames';
import { validEmail } from '@lib/validate-email';

const SendEmail: FC = () => {
    const { setModalView } = useUI();
    const [inputE1, setInputE1] = useState('');
    const [inputE2, setInputE2] = useState('');
    const [inputE3, setInputE3] = useState('');
    const [inputE4, setInputE4] = useState('');
    // const inputText = useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>(null);
    const [dirty, setDirty] = useState(false);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const userSend = async (e: SyntheticEvent<EventTarget>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // const prod = `drisdell.org/api/nodemailer`;
        // const dev = '/api/nodemailer';
        if (!dirty && !disabled) {
            setDirty(true);
            handleValidation();
        }
        setLoading(true);
        setMessage('');
        let res = await fetch('/api/nodemailer', {
            body: JSON.stringify({
                text: inputE3,
                subject: inputE4,
                name: inputE2,
                email: inputE1
            }),
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: 'POST'
        });

        const { error, data } = await res.json();

        if (error) {
            setMessage(error);
            return;
        }
        setLoading(false);
        setInputE1('');
        setInputE2('');
        setInputE3('');
        setInputE4('');
        setMessage(
            'Success  email sent! We will get back to you within several business days' +
                `${data}`
        );
        await setModalView('SUCCESS_VIEW');
    };

    const handleValidation = useCallback(() => {
        if (dirty) {
            setDisabled(!validEmail(inputE1) || !inputE2 || !inputE3 || !inputE4);
        }
    }, [inputE1, inputE2, inputE3, inputE4, dirty]);

    useEffect(() => {
        handleValidation();
    }, [handleValidation]);

    return (
        <form
            onSubmit={userSend}
            className={cn('w-100 flex flex-col justify-between')}
        >
            <div className='flex justify-center pb-4 '>
                <Logo className='h-20 w-20 md:h-40 md:w-40 rounded-full' />
            </div>
            <div className='relative max-w-xl mx-auto'>
                <ModalBackdrop />
                {message && (
                    <div className='text-white border border-white p-2 mb-2 rounded-2xl'>
                        {message}
                    </div>
                )}
                <label htmlFor='email'>{'Email Address'}</label>
                <Input
                    id='from-input'
                    name='from'
                    placeholder='user@example.net'
                    onChange={setInputE1}
                    required={true}
                    type='email'
                    className='mb-2 bg-primary-9 text-primary-0 font-medium focus:outline-none rounded-md'
                />
                <label htmlFor='name'>{'Full Name'}</label>
                <Input
                    id='name-input'
                    name='name'
                    placeholder='first &amp; last names'
                    onChange={setInputE2}
                    required={true}
                    type='text'
                    className='mb-2 bg-primary-9 text-primary-0 font-medium focus:outline-none rounded-md'
                />
                <label htmlFor='subject'>{'Subject'}</label>
                <Input
                    id='subject-input'
                    name='subject'
                    placeholder='Email subject...'
                    onChange={setInputE4}
                    required={true}
                    type='text'
                    className='mb-2 bg-primary-9 text-primary-0 font-medium focus:outline-none rounded-md'
                />
                <label htmlFor='text'>{'Body'}</label>
                <Textarea
                    id='text-textarea'
                    name='text'
                    placeholder='Email body...'
                    onChange={setInputE3}
                    required={true}
                    minLength={5}
                    cols={1}
                    className='mb-2 bg-primary-9 text-primary-0 font-medium focus:outline-none rounded-md'
                />
                <div className='w-auto px-8 flex flex-col'>
                    <Button
                        type='submit'
                        variant='slim'
                        loading={loading}
                        disabled={disabled}
                        className={cn(
                            css.root,
                            'my-4 w-auto max-w-sm bg-primary-7 text-primary-0 hover:bg-primary-9 rounded-md duration-150 transition-colors'
                        )}
                    >
                        {'SUBMIT EMAIL'}
                    </Button>
                </div>
                <span className='pt-1 text-center text-sm'>
                    <span className='text-primary-9'>Interested in a Career?</span>
                    &nbsp;
                    <a
                        className='text-primary-9 font-bold hover:underline cursor-pointer'
                        onClick={() => setModalView('SUBMIT_RESUME_VIEW')}
                    >
                        Submit a Resume
                    </a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
};

export default SendEmail;
```

`pages/api/nodemailer.ts`

```
import nodemailer, { SentMessageInfo } from 'nodemailer';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import secrets from 'aws';
import Mail from 'nodemailer/lib/mailer';
const {
    SMTP_SENDER_ADDRESS,
    SMTP_RECIPIENT_ADDRESS,
    SMTP_PASSWORD,
    SMTP_USERNAME,
    SMTP_BCC_ADDRESS
} = secrets;
const senderAddress = SMTP_SENDER_ADDRESS;
const toAddress = SMTP_RECIPIENT_ADDRESS;
const ccAddress = SMTP_SENDER_ADDRESS;
const bccAddress = SMTP_BCC_ADDRESS;
const smtpUsername = SMTP_USERNAME;
const smtpPassword = SMTP_PASSWORD;

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    const { text, subject, name, email } = req.body;
    try {
        const body_subject = `Contact Us Submission Event - ${subject}`;
        const body_text = `Contact Us Form Submission via AWS SES & Nodemailer
    ---------------------------------------------------------
    ${text}
    `;
        const body_html = `<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h1>${subject}</h1>
        \n
        <h2>Name: ${name}</p>
        \n
        <h2>email: ${email}</h2>
        \n
        <p>${text}</p>
    </body>
    </html>`;
        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: 'email-smtp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com',
            port: 465,
            secure: true,
            auth: {
                user: smtpUsername,
                pass: smtpPassword
            }
        });
        let mailOptions: Mail.Options = {
            sender: senderAddress,
            from: `${senderAddress}`,
            to: toAddress,
            cc: ccAddress,
            bcc: bccAddress,
            subject: body_subject,
            text: body_text,
            html: body_html
        };

        let response: SentMessageInfo = transporter.sendMail(
            mailOptions,
            (info, err) => {
                if (!err)
                    console.log(
                        '\n info.message: ',
                        info?.message,
                        '\n info.stack: ',
                        info?.stack,
                        '\n info.name: ',
                        info?.name
                    );
                console.log(err);
                return info;
            }
        );
        if (response === typeof Error) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error:
                    'There was an internal error ⚙... \n Shoot me an email at [Mary.Drisdell@drisdellconsulting.com]'
            });
        }
        return res.status(200).json({ error: '', data: response ?? '' });
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: error.message || error.toString() });
    }
};
```

[Vercel Dev CLI](https://vercel.com/docs/serverless-functions/introduction#local-development)

- While troubleshooting I came across the `vercel dev` command that can be used locally to test api routes in a vercel environment with the next framework. That said, I have been utilizing this new dev script and it results in a near-instant delivery to targeted addresses with no errors all the same...
  [image]

Vercel real-time serverless function log for /api/nodemailer route after sending an email that was never delivered but has also never bounced

[image]

Any thoughts? I have tried just about everything including quadruple checking my environmental secrets in production. The DNS records tied to the primary domain for SES match up, as does the `unlimited AWS SES Access` Programmatic IAM policy I've configured. Any help would be tremendously appreciated as I have been troubleshooting this daily since last weekend.

The live production site where you can send an email is [here](https://drisdell.org/contact-us).
[image]